# Normalizing a database where B depends on A, C depends on A, but D depends on B+C

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization

Let's say I'm keeping a shipping record of products I sell.

```
Product | Type | Year Made | Item Cost | Shipping Cost | Total Cost | Sold to | Sale Date |
--------+------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------------+---------+------------
Ford 30 | Car  | 1962      | 1000      | 500           | 1500       | Bob     | 01/22/123 |
BOXXXXX | Box  | 1223      | 5         | 10            | 15         | Sam     | 03/44/321 |
```

How do I normalize the last 3 columns? Also, am I missing any thing in achieving 3NF?

Comment: It rather depends on the table's predicate, which is darn hard to guess from just the column names and a single row of data.  So, what does it mean that the row presented appears in your table?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Better?

Comment: somewhat better, yes.

Comment: So the question pertains mainly to the fact that `Total Cost` is a function of `Item Cost` and `Shipping Cost`, yes?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, and I was also wondering if the sold to and sale date conforms to 3NF...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that there are no constraints on `Item Cost` and `Total Cost` (in particular, that they may be both individually and pairwise duplicated in different rows) the pair do not form a superkey of the table.  The table therefore cannot be in third normal form if it contains any other column that is functionally dependent on that pair alone.

If `Total Cost` is expected always to be equal to `Item Cost` + `Shipping Cost`, that constitutes a functional dependency on `Item Cost` and `Shipping Cost`, which means the table is not in 3NF.  You can convert your table to 3NF by dropping the `Total Cost` column.  Your clue here might be that dropping the column would not lose any data.

If you postulated a computing system that could not perform arithmetic (or a relationship that was not directly calculable) then instead of dropping `Total Cost` altogether, you could move it to a separate table having columns (`Item Cost`, `Shipping Cost`, `Total Cost`).  That seems pretty silly for this particular case, though.

I don't see any normalization issues with the `Sold to` and `Sale Date` columns. As far as I can tell, each depends exclusively on the `Product` column, which I take as the the sole member of the only candidate key of the table.

Comment: Mind if I ask another quick question?

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013, if your additional question is a closely related extension of what you've already asked, then go ahead.  Otherwise, it might be better posed as a new top-level question.